# Integration by substitution -- (geometric) Interpretation?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose that $\varphi$ is a smooth path from $a$ to $b$ and $f$ is a differentiable function. Then
$$\int_a^b f(x)\:\mathrm dx = \int_0^1f'\big(\varphi(t)\big)\varphi'(t)\:\mathrm dt.$$ How can I interpret the two factors? $\varphi'$ is clearly the movement along the path. But what about $f'$? Is it valid to say that if $f'(\varphi(t))$ is small, I move "slower" along the path since the product will be small?